# Get the size of the result of aggregate method MongoDB

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo-3.x

I have this aggregate query :

```
cr = db.last_response.aggregate([

{"$unwind": '$blocks'},
{"$match": {"sender_id": "1234", "page_id": "563921", "blocks.tag": "pay1"}},
{"$project": {"block": "$blocks.block"}}
])
```

Now i want to get the number of element it returned (is it empty cursor or not).

This is how i did :
I defined an empty array :

```
x = []
```

I iterated through the cursor and append the array x:

```
for i in cr :
   x.append(i['block'])
print("length of the result of aggregation cursor :",len(x))
```

My question is : Is there any faster way to get the number of the result of aggregate query like the count() method of the find() query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The faster way is that reject operations of transfers all data from mongod to you application. To do this you may add final group stage to count docs

```
{"$group": {"_id": None, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
```

This is mean that mongod do aggregate and get as result count of docs.
Thereis no way to get count of result without execution of aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Now you can use the [$count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/#:~:text=The%20%24match%20stage%20excludes%20documents,to%20a%20field%20called%20passing_scores%20.) aggregate function.
Alternatively, perhaps the [countDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#mongodb-method-db.collection.countDocuments) method could help.